Create table with hashbytes in Synapse dedicated SQL
In SQL server, I am able to create a table with hashbytes without issue.  For example,
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test]
(
  [col1] [int] NOT NULL,
  [col2] [varchar](200) NULL,
  [col_hash] as (hashbytes('SHA2_256', CONCAT([col1],[col2])))
)

However, it reported an error of using 'as' in Synapse dedicated SQL.
Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Parse error at line: 5, column: 13: Incorrect syntax near 'as'.
If not available in Synapse SQL, any other way can do the same?

Looks like you can't create calculated columns on Synapse, but you can still use Hashbytes to create a hash in your code and insert it into the column.
